# XMLPullParser END TAG Error

Tags: java, android, rss, xmlpullparser

I have a loose html img tag in some incoming RSS that I am parsing.  Meaning there is no end tag.  I have zero control of the incoming feed, so I'm stuck.  Is there anyway I can skip this tag.  Everything works fine till I hit the tag.

Here's the exception.

```
06-07 15:46:14.704: ERROR/RSS Downloader(1162): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: END_TAG expected (position:START_TAG (empty) <img src='/ubbthreads/images/graemlins/smile.gif' alt=''>@29:212 in java.io.InputStreamReader@405405f8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply caught the exception and handled it.